# onClick / onclick does not seem to be working as expected in HTML5 / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do something very simple - call a function when a button is clicked. I've looked at several examples online, such as W3Schools and (I believe) I am using onclick / onClick correctly it does not seem to be functioning. I have tried several different methods - I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**Method 1**

HTML

```
<button id="buttonAdd" onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function add() {
    console.log("Test"); 
}
```

Result:

> Test

When the button is clicked this flashes up in the console.log faster than I can easily see and then disappears.

**Method 2**

HTML

```
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

JavaScript

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("add").onclick = add; 
} 

function add() {
    console.log("Test"); 
}
```

Result

> Test

When the button is clicked this flashes up in the console.log faster than I can easily see and then disappears.

**Method 3**

HTML

```
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

JavaScript

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("add").onclick = add(); 
} 

function add() {
    console.log("Test"); 
}
```

Result

> Test

This appears in the console log and remains there, without the button having been clicked.

**Issue**

I'm generally feeling confused. From what I can tell I am doing what is suggested by examples (the different methods I have tried reflect differences in examples).

Thanks.

**Edit**

So it seems the issue is the console.log flashing up almost faster than I can see... Does anyone have any idea why this might be? It seems like the page is refreshing itself, but I have no idea why this would be...

**Answer**

The button was in a form which caused the page to refresh when it was clicked.

Comment: actually the Method 1 works fine.
Both in Chrome and IE.

Comment: the Method 3 is wrong. Trying to asign the `onclick` with `add()` will actually execut the `add` function and assign `onclick` with whatever `add` returns, so, nothing.

Comment: true as that may be @Sho, it's bad practice to usurp names.

Comment: is your button in a form ? because if so, then the form is submited and that's why the the page refreshes. can you post a jsfiddle with your test ?

Comment: Oh geez, that's why... Thank you! 

Could you add this as an answer so I can select it, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the problem is the name of your function. it is the same as the id of the element. do a test an try writing this `console.log(add)`. You will see it logs the DOM node and not the function.

is your button in a form ? because if so, then the form is submited and that's why the the page refreshes. can you post a jsfiddle with your test ?

Comment: yep, seems with a literal reference to the onclick function OF that DOM element, the engine is no longer confused, whereas in the first example, there is ambiguity in the naming. Good call. Addresses a deeper issue, that of consistent naming practices.

Comment: I've altered the name of the function. I still have the issue where 'Test' appears in the console log and disappears almost faster than I can see.

Answer (score 1):

#### Regarding Method 1:

I would need to see a bit more of your html structure to say for sure, but it sounds like in Method 1, the function isn't being declared properly in a way that is in scope. That might have to do with the names being the same, as [theBrain mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15949644/259014) or it might caused by some other problem.

Edit: From your response to theBrain, it sounds like you are able to get method 1 to work if you use different names. Given that, you can also prevent the page post by changing the onclick to include a return false value. Either of the following will work:

```
<button id="buttonAdd" onclick="add(); return false;">Add</button>
```

or

```
<button id="buttonAdd" onclick="return add();">Add</button>
```

coupled with the addition of `return false;` as the last line of your `add()` function's code.

#### Regarding Method 2:

In either case, method 2 is a better way of implementing this, so we can sort of ignore the reasons behind method 1 failing (though having distinctly different names for the function vs the button element would certainly be a good practice; personally, I preface all of my button ids with 'btn_').

The likely reason for the super-fast clearing of the console in both methods is that you do not have a `type` declared for the button. Different browsers do things differently in the absence of a type (see the tip on the [W3Schools Button Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)), and it sounds like yours is treating this as a submit button, which means that it posts back to the page when clicked. You should be able to prevent this behavior by specifying `type='button'` within the attributes of the button element.

#### Regarding Method 3:

Finally, method 3 is providing the behavior that it is because your assignment statement is also executing a call to the `add()` function.

Answer (score 0):

> When the button is clicked this flashes up in the console.log faster than I can easily see and then disappears.

This is suspicious – console output is normally not cleared without user interaction.

Could it be that your page just gets reloaded – and therefor the console output “disappears”?

---

In general, you should not use this kind of “old-school” event handling any more anyway (unless it is for something really small-scale).

Have a look at popuplar JS libraries like jQuery etc. – they simplify event handling (amongst other things) at lot.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was a little different, though I got help from @TheBrain's answer. Name of my javascript method was `submit()`, which was actually submitting my form. When I changed name of method to `submitForm()`, it worked.

I think earlier `submit()` was internally calling Javascript `Form`'s `submit()` and not my javascript method.

Corrections invited.